Can I have numbers on all telescope.nvim picker results, like with ":Telescope buffers"?
When I do :Telescope buffers to picker from a buffer list, there are numbers for each buffer. I know those are just vim buffer numbers, but having numbers for each result in Telescope would be convenient.


Those are buffer numbers and don’t make much sense in other pickers. If you want to quickly navigate to an entry in any picker, and if you are using something like flash.nvim, it has integration in telescope as well, you can press s in normal mode in telescope picker and there appears a char in front of each entry that you can press the char to navigate to that entry.
